# 2D Game Background Parallax Multiple Layers

Tags: camera, 2d, parallax, platform-agnostic

I am having trouble wrapping my head around the following scenario for a parallax background system in a 2D sidescrolling game.

[image: parallax scroll problem]

Layer 1 is visible when the game starts and scrolls along with the camera at a factor of 0.5. Eventually, layer 1 will come to an end and layer 2 needs to be visible so there is no horizontal gap between the two layers. If both layers were moving at the same speed it would be simple, the start of layer 2 could be placed at the end of layer 1. However, in this scenario layer 2 moves slower than layer 1 and so will have to be positioned earlier on the X axis to prevent a gap between the two positions. All background layers are moving relative to the camera.

The system I am trying to create needs to be flexible and support different scroll factors and constantly alternating between layers. Can anyone provide a solution to the problem?

Comment: you realise that the seam will never line up across the entire window, right? As in, you can make it line up perfectly as it enters on the right, but they will be overlapping or have a gap by the time they get to the left.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I tried to visualise with the faded out green box, that they have to overlap for there to be no gap between the layers.

Answer (score 1):

> If both layers were moving at the same time it would be simple

Do you mean "if both layers were moving at the same SPEED it would be simple"? Based on your drawing, here's the formula and some sample numbers:

```
w1 = width of layer 1 = ? (lets say 1000)
s1 = speed of scrolling for layer 1 = 0.5
s2 = speed of scrolling for layer 2 = 0.25
x2 = start x position of layer 2

x2 = (1 - (s2/s1)) * w1

500 = (1 - (0.25/0.5)) * 1000
```

If it moved 5 times slower

```
800 = (1 - (0.1/0.5)) * 1000
```